# Nested loop to several arrays with jolt library

Tags: json, jolt, data-transform

In input, I have a list of persons. Each person has several addresses and roles on contract.
Example :

- Person #001 has :

  - two addresses secondary residence and tax address ;
  - two roles co-subscriber and insured
- Person #002 has :

  - two addresses (i) principal residence and tax address ;
  - three roles co-subscriber, insured and premium payer.

```
{
  "personnes": [
    {
      "refExternePersonne": "BGHT34271",
      "isPersonnePhysique": true,
      "rolesContrat": [
        "CO_SOUSCRIPTEUR",
        "ASSURE"
      ],
      "adresses": [
        {
          "typeAdresse": "RESIDENCE_SECONDAIRE"
        },
        {
          "typeAdresse": "FISCALE"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "refExternePersonne": "BGHT34272",
      "isPersonnePhysique": false,
      "rolesContrat": [
        "SOUSCRIPTEUR",
        "PAYEUR_PRIMES",
        "ASSURE"
      ],
      "adresses": [
        {
          "typeAdresse": "FISCALE"
        },
        {
          "typeAdresse": "CORRESPONDANCE"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Why my spec is incorrect?

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "personnes": {
        "*": {
          "refExternePersonne": "parties[&1].partyRef",
          "rolesContrat": {
            "*": {
              "SOUSCRIPTEUR": {
                "@(3,isPersonnePhysique)": {
                  "true": {
                    "#%phys%": "tickets.processId"
                  },
                  "false": {
                    "#%morale%": "tickets.processId"
                  }
                },
                "@(3,refExternePersonne)": "policies.subscribers[].partyRef",
                "@(3,idPersonne)": "policies.subscribers[].partyId",
                "@(3,adresses)": "policies.subscribers[].addressesTemp"
              },
              "CO_SOUSCRIPTEUR": {
                "@(3,refExternePersonne)": "policies.cosubscribers[].partyRef",
                "@(3,idPersonne)": "policies.cosubscribers[].partyId",
                "@(3,adresses)": "policies.cosubscribers[].addressesTemp"
              },
              "ASSURE": {
                "@(3,refExternePersonne)": "policies.insured[].partyRef",
                "@(3,idPersonne)": "policies.insured[].partyId",
                "@(3,adresses)": "policies.insured[].addressesTemp"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I try to group people with their addresses according to their role on the contract:

- people with the subscriber role are grouped in policies.subscribers[]
- insured role => policies.insured[]
- role co-subscriber => policies.cosubscribers[]

Expected output:

```
{
  "parties": [
    {
      "partyRef": "BGHT34271"
    },
    {
      "partyRef": "BGHT34272"
    }
  ],
  "policies": {
    "cosubscribers": [
      {
        "partyRef": "BGHT34271",
        "addressesTemp": [
          {
            "typeAdresse": "RESIDENCE_SECONDAIRE"
          },
          {
            "typeAdresse": "FISCALE"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "insured": [
      {
        "partyRef": "BGHT34271",
        "addressesTemp": [
          {
            "typeAdresse": "RESIDENCE_SECONDAIRE"
          },
          {
            "typeAdresse": "FISCALE"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "partyRef": "BGHT34272",
        "addressesTemp": [
          {
            "typeAdresse": "FISCALE"
          },
          {
            "typeAdresse": "CORRESPONDANCE"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "subscribers": [
      {
        "partyRef": "BGHT34272",
        "addressesTemp": [
          {
            "typeAdresse": "FISCALE"
          },
          {
            "typeAdresse": "CORRESPONDANCE"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "tickets": {
    "processId": "%morale%"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you'd better thinking with the logic of looping such as

```json
[
  { // grouping by elements of "rolesContrat" 
    // and then by "refExternePersonne" values phase
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "personnes": {
        "*": {
          "refExternePersonne": "parties[&1].partyRef",
          "rolesContrat": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "@3,refExternePersonne": "&.&2.partyRef",
                "@3,adresses": "&.&2.addressesTemp",
                "@3,isPersonnePhysique": "&.&2.PP"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // renaming phase
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "parties": "&",
      "CO_SOU*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "policies.cosubscribers[#2].&"
        }
      },
      "ASSURE": {
        "*": {
          "*": "policies.insured[#2].&"
        }
      },
      "SOUS*": {
        "*": {
          "PP": {
            "true": {
              "#%phys%": "tickets.processId"
            },
            "false": {
              "#%morale%": "tickets.processId"
            }
          },
          "*": "policies.subscribers[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // phase of removing the extra attribute which is "PP" 
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "PP": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: If I swap "ASSURE" in first position in both cases then the mapping fails. Maybe regroup by person instead of roles?
//...
"@3,refExternePersonne": "&.&4.partyRef",
"@3,adresses": "&.&4.addressesTemp",
"@3,isPersonnePhysique": "&.&4.PP"
//... What do you think?

Comment: The question already includes completely customized condition, I mean that's up to you and your choice and I already answered based on the question @gbouget

Comment: Yes, this logic seems to work well: role value (&) / person index (&4)